# Jquery check radio button on keyup

Tags: jquery, onkeyup

I have two radio buttons set and i want is if i will select yes on first set it should automatically select other one as yes here's my code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="saver" value="yes" id="saver"> Yes 
<input type="checkbox" name="saver" value="no" id="saver"> No 

<input type="checkbox" name="sendmail" value="yes" id="sendmail"> Yes
<input type="checkbox" name="sendmail" value="no" id="sendmail"> No
```

So i want is if i select yes on the first set it should select the yes on second set automatically , Jquery goes here

```
$('#saver').keyup(function(){
   var checkbox_value = $('#saver:checked').val();

   if(checkbox_value == 'yes')
   {
      $('input[name="sendmail"]').attr('checked', true);
   }
});
```

It do select the other set automatically but it is going to no instead of yes

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML needs to use unique ID's

```
<input type="checkbox" name="saver" value="yes" id="saver-yes"> Yes 
<input type="checkbox" name="saver" value="no" id="saver-no"> No 

<input type="checkbox" name="sendmail" value="yes" id="sendmail-yes"> Yes
<input type="checkbox" name="sendmail" value="no" id="sendmail-no"> No
```

This javascript is simple (and works - see proof: http://jsfiddle.net/kSVx7/1/)

```
$('#saver-yes').change(function() {

  if($('#saver-yes:checked').val() == 'yes')
     $('#sendmail-yes').attr('checked', true);


});
```

By using change instead of keyup, you can also act on mouseclicks (or even touch events).

By refering to unique id's there is no ambiguity in which element you are refering to, so jQuery knows what to operate on.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$('#saver').change(function() {
    var checkbox_value = $('#saver:checked').val();

    if (checkbox_value == 'yes') {
        $('input[name="sendmail"][value="yes"]').attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

I've changed the 'keyup' event to 'change' but you could change it back to 'keyup' if you preferred.

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/XyKM7/

Answer (score 0):

An ID can only be defined once and you should use change instead of keyup.

http://jsfiddle.net/7hq2V/1/

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="saver" value="yes" id="saver-yes"> Yes 
<input type="checkbox" name="saver" value="no" id="saver-no"> No 

<input type="checkbox" name="sendmail" value="yes" id="sendmail-yes"> Yes
<input type="checkbox" name="sendmail" value="no" id="sendmail-no"> No
```

JS:

```
$('#saver-yes').change(function() {
    if ($(this,':checked')) {
        $('#sendmail-yes').attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things...

If the values within each checkbox group are mutually exclusive then radiobuttons would be a more semantically correct choice.

Secondly the part of script that sets the value is not targeting only the 'yes' checkbox, but the whole group - you need to add another filter to do that:

$('input[name="sendmail"][value="yes"]').attr('checked', true)

If you leave them as checkboxes you'll also need to deal with un-checking the no box.